# All web notifications have completely stopped. How can I fix this?

Tags: google-chrome, notifications, web-notifications

I recently added Notify.js to my add to display web notifications to my users. It was working but all of a sudden I got absolutely NO notifications. Not from any site.

The notifications settings for chrome are still the same. Just cannot receive any notifications. I am dumbfounded. What is going on? Nothing has changed but my computer cannot get any notifications.

Answer (score 1):

on my mac DO NOT DISTURB was turned on. FML